# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory on Glassfish Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I am studying JSF by implementing a web project. These ae my environment and tools:

```
 -Netbeans 7.2.1  
 -Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2  
 -JSF 2.1  
 -Hibernate   
 -Oracle 11gr2
```

I use stateless EJB session beans to obtain data from entity classes, using persistence units which I have defined in my persistence.xml. I access these persistence units like this:

```
private Session session;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistence")
private EntityManager entityManager;  

session= (Session)((EntityManagerImpl)entityManager.getDelegate()).getDelegate();
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>--jndi name--</jta-data-source>
    <class>....</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I was able to create a JDBC connection pool and ping it from my Glassfish server's admin console. But when running my stateless session bean I get this error:

> "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory"

Due to this error, the project can't deploy. How can I solve this problem?
That is stack trace:

```
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO: Hibernate EntityManager 3.3.2.GA
INFO: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistence
    ...]
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.IcerikListe
INFO: Binding named native query: listeOlustur => call PROC_LISTE_EKLE(:P_LISTE_ID,:P_LISTE_AD)
INFO: Binding named native query: listeGuncelle => call PROC_LISTE_GUNCELLE(:P_LISTE_ID,:P_LISTE_AD)
INFO: Binding named native query: listeSil => call PROC_LISTE_SIL(:P_LISTE_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: listeDondur => call PROC_LISTELER(?)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.IcerikListe on table TBL_ICERIK_LISTE
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.Kategori
INFO: Binding named native query: kategoriEkle => call PROC_KATEGORI_EKLE(:P_KATEGORI_AD)
INFO: Binding named native query: kategoriGuncelle => call PROC_KATEGORI_GUNCELLE(:P_KATEGORI_AD,:P_KATEGORI_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: kategoriSil => call PROC_KATEGORI_SIL(:P_KATEGORI_ID)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.Kategori on table TBL_KATEGORI
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.Kullanici
INFO: Binding named native query: kullaniciOlustur => call PROC_KULLANICI_EKLE(:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_KULLANICI_AD,:P_SIFRE,:P_AD,:P_SOYAD,
:P_UYELIK_TRH,:P_UYELIK_AYRILMA_TRH)
INFO: Binding named native query: kullaniciGuncelle => call PROC_KULLANICI_GUNCELLE(:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_KULLANICI_AD,:P_SIFRE, :P_AD,:P_SOYAD, 
:P_UYELIK_TRH,:P_UYELIK_AYRILMA_TRH)
INFO: Binding named native query: kullaniciSil => call PROC_KULLANICI_SIL(:P_KULLANICI_ID,: P_TRH)
INFO: Binding named native query: icerikEkleyenKullanici => call PROC_ICERIK_EKLEYEN_KULLANICI(?,:P_ICERIK_ID)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.Kullanici on table TBL_KULLANICI
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.Icerik
INFO: Binding named native query: icerikEkle => call PROC_ICERIK_EKLE(:P_LISTE_ID,:P_KATEGORI_ID,:P_EKLEME_TRH,:P_ICERIK_AD,
:P_INCELENME_SAYI,:P_INDIRILME_SAYI,:P_DOSYA_YOLU,:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_TELIF_ACIKLAMA,
:P_TICARI_KULLANILABILIRLIK)
INFO: Binding named native query: icerikGuncelle => call PROC_ICERIK_GUNCELLE(:P_ICERIK_ID,:P_LISTE_ID,:P_EKLEME_TRH,:P_INCELENME_SAYI,
:P_INDIRILME_SAYI,:P_DOSYA_YOLU,:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_TELIF_ACIKLAMA,:P_TICARI_KULLANILABILIRLIK,
:P_KATEGORI_ID,:P_ICERIK_AD)
INFO: Binding named native query: icerikSil => call PROC_ICERIK_SIL(:P_ICERIK_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: benzerIcerikler => call PROC_BENZER_ICERIKLER(?,:P_ICERIK_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: listedeYerAlanIcerikler => call PROC_LISTEDEKI_ICERIKLER(?,:P_LISTE_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: ayniListedeYerAlanIcerikler => call PROC_AYNI_LISTEDEKI_ICERIKLER(?,:P_ICERIK_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: enSonEklenenler => call PROC_EN_SON_EKLENENLER(?)
INFO: Binding named native query: enCokIncelenenler => call PROC_EN_COK_INCELENENLER(?)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.Icerik on table TBL_ICERIK
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.Mesaj
INFO: Binding named native query: mesajOlustur => call PROC_MESAJ_OLUSTUR(:P_KONU,:P_BASLIK,:P_MESAJ_TRH,:P_GONDEREN_ID,:P_ALAN_ID,:P_OKUNDU_MU,
:P_SILINDI_MI,:P_EKLI_MI,:P_MESAJ)
INFO: Binding named native query: mesajGuncelle => call PROC_MESAJ_GUNCELLE(:P_MESAJ_ID,:P_KONU,:P_BASLIK,:P_MESAJ_TRH,:P_GONDEREN_ID,:P_ALAN_ID,:P_OKUNDU_MU,
:P_SILINDI_MI,:P_EKLI_MI,:P_MESAJ)
INFO: Binding named native query: mesajSil => call PROC_MESAJ_SIL(:P_MESAJ_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: mesajOkundu => call PROC_MESAJ_OKUNDU(:P_MESAJ_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: okunanMesajlar => call PROC_OKUNAN_MESAJLAR(?,:P_KULLANICI_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: silinenMesajlar => call PROC_SILINEN_MESAJLAR(?,:P_KULLANICI_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: gelenMesajlar => call PROC_GELEN_MESAJLAR(?,:P_KULLANICI_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: gidenMesajlar => call PROC_GONDERILEN_MESAJLAR(?,:P_KULLANICI_ID)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.Mesaj on table TBL_MESAJ
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.csp.entity.Yorum
INFO: Binding named native query: yorumEkle => call PROC_YORUM_OLUSTUR(:P_ICERIK_ID,:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_YORUM,:P_YORUM_TRH)
INFO: Binding named native query: yorumGuncelle => call PROC_YORUM_GUNCELLE(:P_YORUM_ID,:P_ICERIK_ID,:P_KULLANICI_ID,:P_YORUM,:P_YORUM_TRH)
INFO: Binding named native query: yorumSil => call PROC_YORUM_SIL(:P_YORUM_ID)
INFO: Binding named native query: icerikYapilanYorumlar => call PROC_ICERIK_YORUMLAR(?,:P_ICERIK_ID)
INFO: Bind entity com.csp.entity.Yorum on table TBL_YORUM
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.IcerikListe.listedekiIcerikler -> TBL_ICERIK
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kategori.kategoriIcerikler -> TBL_ICERIK
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kullanici.alinanMesajlar -> TBL_MESAJ
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kullanici.eklenenIcerikler -> TBL_ICERIK
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kullanici.gonderilenMesajlar -> TBL_MESAJ
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kullanici.listeler -> TBL_ICERIK_LISTE
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Kullanici.yapilanYorumlar -> TBL_YORUM
INFO: Mapping collection: com.csp.entity.Icerik.yorumlar -> TBL_YORUM
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: [PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.csp.entity.IcerikListe column: KULLANICI_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:652)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1102)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1287)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    ... 37 more

SEVERE: java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5: Error in formatting Logrecord
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.hibernate.exception.ExceptionUtils], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate.printStackTrace(NestableDelegate.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.printStackTrace(NestableRuntimeException.java:195)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:351)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:162)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
    at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:105)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:522)
    at com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1.log(LogDomains.java:372)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:543)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:632)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:481)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
SEVERE:     at org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate.printStackTrace(NestableDelegate.java:325)
SEVERE:     at org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.printStackTrace(NestableRuntimeException.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:351)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:162)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:105)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:522)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1.log(LogDomains.java:372)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:543)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:632)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:481)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5: Error in formatting Logrecord
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.hibernate.exception.ExceptionUtils], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate.printStackTrace(NestableDelegate.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.printStackTrace(NestableRuntimeException.java:195)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:351)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:162)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.log(GFFileHandler.java:659)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler$1.run(GFFileHandler.java:179)

SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
SEVERE:     at org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate.printStackTrace(NestableDelegate.java:325)
SEVERE:     at org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.printStackTrace(NestableRuntimeException.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:351)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:162)
SEVERE:     at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:196)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.log(GFFileHandler.java:659)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler$1.run(GFFileHandler.java:179)
```

Comment: Did you redact content from this line - `<jta-data-source>--jndi name--</jta-data-source>`, or is that really what is in your persistence.xml? Also, you do not need a `<classes>` element when you specify `exclude-unlisted-classes=false`. Especially if it really has `....` as its value, thats just wrong.

Comment: jndi name that I created for access database I add it persistence.xml,in classes tag i wrote complete class name like com.csp.entity.classname,when i don't add  exclude-unlisted-classes=false ,it gives me same error

Comment: Add to your question, the complete error stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is reported in your exception stacktrace (in about the middle portion of it):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: com.csp.entity.IcerikListe column: KULLANICI_ID (should be
>   mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:652)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:674)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:450)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:192)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1102)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1287)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
>       ... 37 more

Fix the offending entity (`com.csp.entity.IcerikListe`) and try your build/deploy again.